# MongoDB backup strategy for AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, database-backups

If I have mongodb running in an EC2 instance that is being written to (somewhat) constantly what is the most intelligent, safe, and inexpensive backup strategy.

My concern is that if an EC2 instance goes down you lose any data written to disk...

Answer (score 7):

Old question but I think that I can contribute with more details and informations about a real success case.

In a production environment I have 3 Mongodb with replicaset running in 3 T2.micro instances, 1 instance is the primary, 1 instance is the secondary and 1 instance is delayed (every 4 hours is synchronized) with persistent EBS (it's not deleted after instance reboot).
Every 4.5 hours I start a Lambda process that makes a EBS snapshot of delayed instance and sends to a S3 bucket.
This is working pretty well.

Some links that can help:

- [Scheduling EBS Snapshots - Part I](https://serverlesscode.com/post/lambda-schedule-ebs-snapshot-backups/)
- [Scheduling EBS Snapshots - Part II](https://serverlesscode.com/post/lambda-schedule-ebs-snapshot-backups-2/)

Comment: Do you use a single EBS volume in each of the machines ? There can be problems with snapshots if there are several EBS volumes (RAID) that make up the /data: folder. It may happen that the snapshot takes place during your synchronization. I do not really understand how your "delayed" stuff comes to help here. The [MongoDB Docs on EC2](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tutorial/backup-and-restore-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2/) also suggest locking the DB, and this doesn't seem to be covered in your links.

Comment: Delayed is much more for convenience (in my scenario). Anyway you should execute a rs.fsyncLock() before the EBS snapshot, as you said. In my enviroment I execute the rs.fsyncLock() remotely from a lambda before the EBS snapshot. I'm thinking to write a Medium post explaning what I did to solve things like that, for example, I created a Node.js that receives HTTP commands and execute in my Mongodb so I can call from my lambda to execute, for example, the rs.fsyncLock().

Comment: ... I have one EBS volume attached for each EC2

Comment: Would love to see that Medium post :)

Answer (score 4):

Who better than 10gen (MongoDB developers) to responds you.

You can see in follogin site, official documentation about MongoDB backups in EC2 instances.  http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/

They suggest an EBS snapshots. This solution permits start instance in a few of seconds with a "photo" of your database.

Comment: They have a special tutorial for backup on EC2, although they do not provide automatic scripts/lambda to do it there : [EC2 Backups](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tutorial/backup-and-restore-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2/)

Answer (score 1):

We use (at least two) linux instances with the data stored on EBS and replica sets (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets).

Comment: How often do you snapshot to EBS?

Comment: Replication != backup